# MinGW-w64: Сборка без msvcrt.dll

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64

Использую компилятор MinGW-w64

```
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.2.0
```

Все собранные бинарники зависят от библиотеки `msvcrt.dll`. Как убрать эту библиотеку из зависимостей бинарников или хотя бы использовать вместо неё более новую версию *MSVCRT*, например, `vcruntime140.dll`?

Comment: Каких именно возможностей вам не хватает в msvcrt.dll, которые есть в vcruntime140.dll? Или чем вам мешает msvcrt.dll?

Answer (score 2):

Для линковки с `msvcr120` работал вот такой способ:

```
g++ -dumpspecs > msvcr120.spec
```

Далее, в блокноте открыть файл *msvcr120.spec* и заменить там `-lmsvcrt` на `-lmsvcr120`. А затем, при сборке проекта, указывать опцию `-specs`:

```
g++ -static -specs=msvcr120.spec -s -O2 -o hello.exe hello.cpp
```

Соответственно, заменив `msvcr120` на свою версию вы должны получить желаемое.

---

Важно: используйте ключ `-static`, чтобы избежать динамической линковки с `libstdc++` (и прочими стандартными mingw-библиотеками). Иначе вы всё равно будете зависеть от `msvcrt.dll`, хоть и через третьи руки. Ну, или можете попробовать пересобрать все используемые библиотеки MinGW с зависимостью от нужной вам версии рантайма.

**Upd**: Похоже, что текущая версия MinGW-w64 (7.2.0) не поддерживает линковку с msvcr140 (фьюче-реквест висит с 2015 года: [#77 Visual Studio 2015 runtime support (libmsvcr140.a)](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/feature-requests/77/) ).

Т.е. пока что можно линковаться только с 80, 90, 100, 110 и 120 версиями.